# Why pygame keycodes are os-specific?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, pygame, keycode

I have an engine called [Ergame](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame) that has a module called [erfunc](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame/blob/master/erfunc.py). I wrote it on NT/Windows platform, and now I'm on POSIX/Linux. Since I find input on pygame considerably obscure many times, and I wanted to create an explicit distinction between IBM-STANDARD-US-PC and ABNT2 keyboard layouts, [I've created several constants whose values are pygame-keycodes](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame/blob/master/erdat.py#L70-L101). I have problem.

For example, the keycode for "ACUTE/TILDE" on US-Standard Layout is 96. I've checked many times. Now, on POSIX, when I check, I get 39 (And the same applies to all the others). Which basically means: If I refer to the pygame-name, like pygame.K_UP, whatever. But if I refer to the keycodes directly, they differ according to the OS (Which basically means that I'll have to detect the OS on my engine and define the constants accordingly. Pretty boring.)

Anyway, I got curious. Why?

Comment: If the pygame names work, why don't you just use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I don't have any experience with input on windows or mac systems, but here is whats happening on the linux side.

Key events typically follow a three stage processing before reaching a program. The keyboard generates a scancode. The OS converts the scancode into a keycode. A keyboard map translates the keycode into a symbol.

- Scancodes are hardware specific and represent a location on the keyboard
- Keycodes are values the OS maps to scancodes, usually defined in `/usr/include/linux/input.h`
- Keysyms are the symbols mapped to the keycodes, defined by your keymap. You can check them with `xmodmap -pke`

For SDL (which PyGame acts as a wrapper around), the scancode/keycode distinction is a little fuzzy, and not super important. What it reports as a "scancode" is actually the keycode, you'll notice pygame's`event.scancode` will match the "keycode" value printed in xev. What SDL calls "sym", pygame calls "key" and is really an SDL specific keycode. The keysym is represented by the event's "unicode" value.

The important part of this is that you are not actually getting the raw scancode, so it can be expected to be OS dependent rather than keyboard dependent. Also, if you were getting the raw scancode, you would expect scancodes to be equivalent onposition rather than character. So all row-1 col-1 keys produce the same scancode independent of keyboard layout.

While it may be boring to do OS checks and have massive constant tables, this is typically how its done. The good news is SDL does this for you, so you really should be using the pygame.K_* names. If supporting multiple keyboard layouts is an issue, consider adding an input configuration menu instead of hard coding tables for each layout.

I want to leave some links for further reading, but I'm not really sure what to link to. I'll leave the [SDL Input Guide](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html) here for now.

Comment: That was a very nice answer @kalhartt, thank you very much! I'll check the link. It really became clear that the concept of adding an "input configuration menu" is way better (And I'll also use the names). Actually, I did not know that they would change, so I preferred the keycodes (For example, I could access a series of keycodes by simply checking them and creating a "range constant", a list of them). But I see now. Thank you!